# How to Install XCache on BlueHost VPS

Tags: centos6, php5, xcache

I have a VPS account on BlueHost.  The OS is CentOS6.7 x86_64 and PHP version is 5.4.28.  I followed instructions from [here](http://www.tecmint.com/install-xcache-to-accelerate-and-optimize-php-performance/) to install XCache and the installation failed.  The installation failed again after I enabled EPEL repository.  Below are the installation commend and error message.

> yum install php-xcache xcache-admin

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package php-xcache available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xcache-admin.noarch 0:3.0.4-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-xcache = 3.0.4-1.el6 for package: xcache admin-3.0.4-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mod_php for package: xcache-admin-3.0.4-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: xcache-admin-3.0.4-1.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: xcache-admin-3.0.4-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: mod_php
Error: Package: xcache-admin-3.0.4-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: httpd
Error: Package: xcache-admin-3.0.4-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-xcache = 3.0.4-1.el6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It seems to me EPEL is not the right package.  But what else I should use? Please help me resolve this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have yum excludes configured?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No.  I did no do any configuration on yum.  What should be excluded, why and how?

Comment: Nothing _should_ be excluded, but it looks like something _is_ excluded. Check your yum.conf and all of your yum repos carefully to see if any excludes exist.